# Get access to SQLAlchemy connection socket to prevent firewall timeouts

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am having some issues with my database connections. They seem to be abruptly severed by some firewall in the network and a nice way to fix this at the TCP level seems to be to configure keepalive for a particular TCP socket. The problem is I have no idea how and if it is possible to gain access to the connections managed by SQLAlchemy. I am using it to connect to an Oracle database. This is enabled by the use of cx_Oracle and Oracle's Instant Client which is also installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL*Net option [`EXPIRE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-6140611A-83FC-4C9C-B31F-A41FC2A5B12D) as documented in the [cx_Oracle doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html#network-configuration). `EXPIRE_TIME` can be used to prevent firewalls from terminating idle connections and to adjust keepalive timeouts. The general recommendation for EXPIRE_TIME is to use a value that is slightly less than half of the termination period.

The details:

- With 18c client libraries it can be added as `(EXPIRE_TIME=n)` to the `DESCRIPTION` section of a connect descriptor (in a full connect descriptor string in the app, or in the tnsnames.ora file).
- With 19c client libraries it can be used via Easy Connect: `host/service?expire_time=n`.
- With 21c client libraries it can be used in a client-side (i.e. Python machine) sqlnet.ora.

With older client versions you can use [`ENABLE=BROKEN`](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-7A18022A-E40D-4880-B3CE-7EE9864756CA) instead.

Also consider using a [connection pool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#using-cx-oracle-sessionpool) with SQLAlchemy, since this will do some checks and automatically re-establish connections if they have been killed.  Pools are also great for performance in heavily used, long running apps.

Comment: I already have an sqlnet.ora file and previous tests that I've ran with v 21 seemed to fix the problem.However, I am now on the 19.10 version of the instantclient and for some reason it seems to ignore my sqlnet.ora SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=1 config. I would like to try and pass it as you've recommended via the Easy Connect mechanism, however, attaching this to the connect string usses results in something like this: oracle+cx_oracle_no_clobs://user:pass@host:port/dbname?expire_time=1 and this results in an error thrown from dbapi.connect: TypeError: 'expire_time' is an invalid kw arg for this fn.

Comment: P.S the above connection string is used by SQLAlchemy

Comment: 'Some reason' is that it wasn't supported in the (client side) sqlnet.ora before 21c - as I listed above.  Create yourself a tnsnames.ora file and just reference the connect alias in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Just to confirm ... there is no way to globally enable the keepalive behavior in tsnames for any host, port and SID the user may decide to use at the application level, right?

Comment: Use 21c client and use EXPIRE_TIME in a sqlnet.ora file.